# Magic Squares of Squares

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, additive-combinatorics, magic-square

Let $A =$ $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ and $B =$ $\{b_1, b_2, ..., b_m\}$ be two sets of integers. If $a + b$ is a square for all $ a ∈ A $ and $ b ∈ B $. $A$ and $ B $ are then said to be Square Additive Sets $(SAS)$ and this is denoted by $[a_1, a_2 , ..., a_n][b_1, b_2, ..., b_m]$.

While it is possible to find $3*3$ and $4*4$ $SAS$ ([here](http://www.thomas-egense.dk/math/constructing_magic_squares_of_squares_from_mols.html) you can find some examples), I would like to know if $5*5$ $SAS$ can exist or not.

Comment: Alas, as stated at your link, that's an open question. Feel free to test your coding skills and see how much computing power you have trying to find one!

Comment: Also for the record, this site: http://www.multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquares.htm has a ton more information.  EDIT: Oh, from this site, a 5x5 square of squares is, in fact, no longer open. A 3x3 one is though!

Comment: Well I would like to know if there is a way to prove analytically the existence of such SAS. I guess is something similar to this Euler problem https://plus.maths.org/content/36-officers-problem

Comment: @EricSnyder the problem is slightly different, because we need to find the two Square Additive Sets

Comment: Duplicate question with more information but no definitive answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099983